# Custom QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController that can intercept touch events

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

Ok, so what I am trying to do is create a Document Viewer that is similar this picture:
[image]

Basically what should happen is, when the screen is tapped anywhere, the top and bottom bar will appear.  Tap again and they disappear.

I have subclassed `QLPreviewController` and have managed to leverage the (top) navigation bar that already comes with `QLPreviewController`.  This works fine.  Now I need to get the bottom bar to display whenever the top bar is displayed.  I can add a `UIToolbar` to the bottom of the page, but I need to intercept the touch events so I can hide/unhide the bottom bar.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work.  I tried adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view of the `QLPreviewController` subclass itself to no luck.  I also tried creating an overlay `UIView` that has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` but that prevented the user form interacting with the document underneath.

Anyone have any ideas at all on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what the issue was with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.  You need to set the delegate to self, and then override the

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

function and return yes.  So in my QLPreviewController subclass, I implemented the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, and in the viewWillAppear:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(documentTapped:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[tapGesture autorelease]];
```

Then simply:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

This way, the QLPreviewController will still receive all the other non-tap touch events so that the user can still interact with the document

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `QLPreviewController` and then override

```
-(void)contentWasTappedInPreviewContentController:(id)item {}
```

That's it!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seems to be a valuable solution since apple consider it a private API. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091027/qlpreviewcontrollers-view#comment34156919_22231721